# Image augmentation options in config for Object detection and high loss value using SSD MobileNetv2

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, data-augmentation

I noticed that when I include the image augmentation options like below to train my object detection model the loss value is incredibly high  like 30K and 65K unlike when I dont use these options

Why is that so? note that I have only observed this for first few hundred steps and haven't baby sit my model for too long

65K loss value with these

```
data_augmentation_options {
    random_image_scale {
      min_scale_ratio:0.5
      min_scale_ratio:2
    }
  }  
  data_augmentation_options {
    scale_boxes_to_pixel_coordinates {
    }

      }
```

~30K plus loss value with these

```
data_augmentation_options {
    random_image_scale {
      min_scale_ratio:0.5
      min_scale_ratio:2
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_pixel_value_scale {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    scale_boxes_to_pixel_coordinates {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same just yesterday and came up with the following observation for me. If you just observe a training just for a few steps, it is not able to generalize the whole test set as fast as with a non-augmented data set. Here you have to see an augmented data set like an bigger one, with much more variance in it. But here the information is not available from the first epoch on, it needs some time till this variance is exposed during the training.

So just try to train it longer and observe the outcome, the results should improve.

Comment: Thanks I will keep it running, 
After 4400 steps so far out of 50K the predictions are still zero and loss is still at 34919.176

Comment: 35K steps and loss is no where near converging, still hovering at 29K, what do you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried augmenting the data without `scale_boxes_to_pixel_coordinates`?